# MariaDB 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, mariadb

Trying to migrate my project to a new server which is running Ubuntu 20.04, Default MariaDB version for 20.04 is MariaDB 10.5.

I can't seem to find any details on how to install MariaDB version 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot use the latest version as our project is a little old, there may be a chance the project may break in the latest MariaDB version.

Is there a way to install Mariadb 10.1 on Ubuntu 20.04, or should reinstall the server with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: You say there may be a chance the project may break. Did you try it? I usually did not have problems with backwards compatibility. There must be a way to install 10.1. If not any other way, by compiling it. However, your problems will only grow in that way. It will be more and more difficult to maintain such a system. In my experience, it would be easier, if you try to adapt your project, if adaptation will be needed.